# Get distinct row count in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have below data frame in pyspark. I want to check for every row if it is unique value in a data frame.

Below is the dataframe .

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F



data=[["1","2020-02-01"],["2","2019-03-01"],["3","2021-03-01"],["4",""],["5","2021-21-01"],["6","1900-01-01"],["6","2000-01-01"]]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,["id","input"])
df.show()
```

| id | input |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 |
| 3 | 2019-03-01 |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | 2021-21-01 |
| 6 | 1900-01-01 |
| 6 | 2000-01-01 |

I am looking to get the count of rows to find if the row is unique or not. Below is the output what I am looking for.

| id | CountUnique |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

The below code will give me the count by grouping howerver i need to show count for every row. For example 6 should show two times with 2 row count.

```
df.groupBy("id").count().orderBy("id").show().select("id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count with window functions, i.e. `count(*) over (partition by id)`:

```
df.withColumn('count', F.expr('count(*) over (partition by id)')).show()

+---+----------+-----+
| id|     input|count|
+---+----------+-----+
|  3|2021-03-01|    1|
|  5|2021-21-01|    1|
|  6|1900-01-01|    2|
|  6|2000-01-01|    2|
|  1|2020-02-01|    1|
|  4|          |    1|
|  2|2019-03-01|    1|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Is their any way to remove the input column from above and just show id and count has output

Comment: You can use `selectExpr` to select only columns that you needed. `df.selectExpr('id', 'count(*) over (partition by id) as count').show()`